# MegaCli newly created disk doesn't appear under /dev/sdX

Tags: redhat, udev, megacli

After having successfully added 2 new disks in a new RAID virtual drive (background initialization done), I would have exepected it to appear under /dev/sdh but it's not there (so, unusable).

The system is running a CentOS 5.2 64 bits, HAL and udev daemons are running, not records of any sdh apparition under the messsage log file or in dmesg, only MegaCli do see that virtual drive.

Any idea ?

Some data:

```
[root@server ~]# ./MegaCli -LDInfo -LALL -a0


Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:

Virtual Disk: 0 (target id: 0)
Name:
RAID Level: Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size:139392MB
State: Optimal
Stripe Size: 64kB
Number Of Drives:2
Span Depth:1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy: Disk's Default
Virtual Disk: 1 (target id: 1)
Name:
RAID Level: Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size:285568MB
State: Optimal
Stripe Size: 64kB
Number Of Drives:2
Span Depth:1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAheadNone, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy: Disk's Default

[root@server ~]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-360*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36001ec90f82fe100108ca0a704098d09 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36001ec90f82fe100108ca0a704098d09-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36001ec90f82fe100108ca0a704098d09-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fe07e78f94940c0000a0ee -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fe07e78f94940c0000a0ee-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fe972a3f91240a0000005f -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fe972a3f91240a0000005f-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fea7e18f94640c000020ec -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fea7e18f94640c000020ec-part1 -> ../../sde1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0feb7da8f94340c0000203d -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0feb7da8f94340c0000203d-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fed7d78f94040c000080b7 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a028e0fed7d78f94040c000080b7-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a05830145e58e0b9c479000010a1 -> ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 17  2010 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36090a05830145e58e0b9c479000010a1-part1 -> ../../sdg1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a rescan of the SCSI bus doing: `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host#/scan`